# I have an error of range using Useform "Method_Default of object range failed

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am creating an useform to create, modify, search and delete data.
when I'm running the code to create data, it shows the error:

Run-time error '-2147417848(80010108)':
Method'_Default' of object 'range'failed.

I have tried to change the object (name of te worksheet.) for (activesheet.) activating the sheet where I am registering the data I want to add but still not working.

The code has several procedures,  but I'm  having trouble just when I am creating new data
At the beginning it worked well but now it has this issue. I am new programming.

The code fails  in this area 
S

```
et oCelda = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        oCelda = consecutivo
```

complete code as follow

```
  Private Sub Cmb_Registro_Click()

   Dim oCelda As Range
    Dim bCheck As Boolean
    Dim Consecutivo as Double, file As long, Col As long, Final  As Long
    Worksheets("Data").Activate

    bCheck = Txt_Fecha <> "" And Cbo_Categoria <> "" And Cbo_Subcategoria <> "" And Txt_Monto <> "" _
    And Cbo_Periodo <> "" And Txt_Descripcion <> ""
    Col = 1 
    fila = 2 
    Cbo_Periodo.Enabled = False
        Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(fila, Col) <> Empty
          fila = fila + 1
        Loop
          Final = fila
            Consecutivo = Val(ActiveSheet.Cells(Final - 1, Col)) 
            If Consecutivo = 0 Then 
                consecutivo = 1
            Else
                consecutivo = ActiveSheet.Cells(Final - 1, Col) + 1 
            End If
      If bCheck And optIngreso Then
            *Set oCelda = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            oCelda = consecutivo*
            oCelda.Offset(0, 1) = CDate(Txt_Fecha)
            oCelda.Offset(0, 2) = CLng(Txt_Monto)
            oCelda.Offset(0, 3) = lblIngreso.Caption
            oCelda.Offset(0, 4) = Txt_Descripcion
            oCelda.Offset(0, 5) = Cbo_Categoria
            oCelda.Offset(0, 6) = Cbo_Subcategoria
            oCelda.Offset(0, 7) = Cbo_Periodo

            MsgBox "Registro completo"

            Unload Me 

    ElseIf bCheck And optEgreso Then


    *Set oCelda = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            oCelda = consecutivo*

            oCelda.Offset(0, 1) = CDate(Txt_Fecha)
            oCelda.Offset(0, 2) = CLng(Txt_Monto)
            oCelda.Offset(0, 3) = lblEgreso.Caption
            oCelda.Offset(0, 4) = Txt_Descripcion
            oCelda.Offset(0, 5) = Cbo_Categoria
            oCelda.Offset(0, 6) = Cbo_Subcategoria
            oCelda.Offset(0, 7) = Cbo_Periodo
            MsgBox "Registro completo"
            Unload Me
    Else
            MsgBox "Faltan datos"

    End If
    Worksheets("Inicio").Activate
    End Sub
```

Comment: `Row.Count` is not defined. You mean probably `Rows.Count`. Do you use `Option Explicit`?

Comment: sorry, it is rows.count. I pasted wrong. and I am not sure about Option Explicit. I am a beginner. can you please explain me that

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement

Comment: I checked it, I did not use option explicit @FunThomas

Comment: I already used,  every variable is defined @FunThomas. Still having the issue

Comment: You have defined `Dim Consecutivo, fila, Col, Final  As Long` -- in this case, only `Final` is type `Long`. The other variables are `Variant`. VBA requires that you explicitly type each variable on the same line, so `Dim Consecutivo As Long, fila As Long, Col As Long, Final  As Long`.  The `Val` function returns a `Double`, though, so your `Consectivo` value is really a `Double` (if that's what you intend). Finally, the error is complaining about the "Default" member of the range class. To solve this, make it explicit: `oCelda.Value = consecutivo`.

Comment: @peterT thank you I did the corrections defining the variables correctly. still having the issue

Comment: @peter do you think it has something to do that the row selected is from a table?